# What is the cardinality of the set of fixed points of $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ with $|f'(t)|\leq \frac12$?

Tags: real-analysis

let $f\in C^1[-1,1]$  such that $|f(t)|\leq 1$ and $|f^{'}(t)|\leq \frac{1}{2} \forall t\in [-1,1]$.

let $A=\{t\in [-1,1]:f(t)=t\}$.

is $A\neq \phi $ ?find cardinality of $A$?

I can think that $f\equiv0$ is a function which satisfies this property and in that case $A$ will have cardinality 1.but how to do it effectively ?any hints

Comment: Why did you revert the edits?  E.g., what is wrong with using standard capitalization at the beginning of sentences?  Your notation for the empty set is unusual.  It is not the Greek letter $\phi$, but rather $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $A$ is always nonempty, and this would be true for any continuous $f:[a,b]\to[a,b]$.  You can prove this using the intermediate value theorem.  The [Brouwer fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) generalizes this.

So $A$ has at least one element.  If $A$ had $2$ elements, then by the mean value theorem there would be a point where $f'(x) = 1$.

---

Both existence and uniqueness also follow from a different generalization, the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), because $[a,b]\subset\mathbb R$ is a complete metric space and the mean value theorem implies that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq\frac12|x-y|$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: thanks for your useful answer

Comment: Yep +1.  Note, also, that the proof of Banach's theorem is constructive and yields a way to find the fixed point - simply iterate the function.

Comment: thanks for giving the solution using Banach FPT .It was a boost

Answer (score 0):

Define $g(t) := f(t) -t$. So asking for the points $t$ with $f(t)=t$ is equivalent to asking for the points $t$ with $g(t) = 0$. We have
$$
 g'(t) = f'(t) - 1 \in [-\frac{1}{2} - 1, \frac{1}{2} - 1]
$$
In particular $g'(t) \le -\frac{1}{2} < 0$ for any $t \in [-1,1]$. So $g$ is strictly monotone, and thus there is at most one $t$ with $g(t) = 0$.

There is such a $t$, because $g(-1) = f(-1) + 1 \ge 0$ and $g(1) = f(1) - 1 \le 0$ and because $g$ is continous.